# Point to latlng conversion from Google Earth KML file

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth

Im having issue to extracting the Google Earth coordinates, because I need it to be in latlng and not GPoint, and need to expose to my Google Map app, Im aware that I can use those points to show my data in the gmap, but still need to convert to latlng, my nodejs script its

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    xml2js = require('xml2js');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/doc.xml', function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        var data = [];
        for (var i in result.data.Placemark) {
            var row = result.data.Placemark[i];
            var point = row.Point[0].coordinates.toString().split(',');
            row = {
                name            : row.name[0]
                , description   : row.description[0]
                , geolocation   : [point[0], point[1]]
            };
            data.push(row);
        }

        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

At this point Im able to extract all the data I want (I just removed all the unnecessary tags from the KML). But I need to normalize it to latlng because my other database documents (noSQL) are all in latlng.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the order of point[0] (longitude), point[1] (latitude).

Change:

```
    geolocation   : [point[0], point[1]]
```

To:

```
    geolocation   : [point[1], point[0]]
```

Comment: Google didn't specify [KML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language), it was created by Keyhole, Inc, which was acquired by Google in 2004.